# IDE PyCharm Error: "Cannot find reference 'com_error' in 'pywintypes.py'" but Code Runs Successfully

Tags: python

I'm working with the pywin32 library in Python and trying to catch the pywintypes.com_error exception. However, my IDE keeps showing an error:

```
Cannot find reference 'com_error' in 'pywintypes.py'
```

The interesting part is that when I run the code outside the IDE, it executes without any issues, and the exception is caught as expected.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```py
import pywintypes
import xlwings

wb = xlwings.Book()

try:
    wb.save(f"my_file.xlsm")
except pywintypes.com_error as e:
    print("An error occurred:", e)
```

I'm using `PyCharm 2023.2.1 (Professional Edition)`. I'm not allowed to use the `#noqa` and I'm not allowed any warning in my IDE for this project. Is there a way to solve this issue? I've tried importing `pywintypes.com_error` but it doesn't work either.